# How to have LED Light Notification?

Tags: android

Update: I am reworking the original post for compatibility before Android 3.0.

I am trying to create a simple notification and everything but the light works great.  I do have the screen off when the notification fires. Using this deprecated code sound and vibrations works on Android 4.0 (Galaxy Nexus) and Android 2.3 (HTC EVO).

- On the 2.3 HTC EVO the lights also work.
- On the 4.0 Galaxy Nexus the lights do not work.

  ```
  Notification notification = 
          new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "My Ticker!",System.currentTimeMillis());
  notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "My Title", "My Message", pendingIntent);
  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

  //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

  notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
  notification.ledOnMS = 300;
  notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  ```

I have also tried newer APIs that are not part of the v4 compatibility library, so I could only test this on the Galaxy Nexus.  Vibration and Sound works again but not lights.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("My Ticker")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)
            .setContentTitle("My Title 1")
            .setContentText("My Text 1");
        Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
```

I have now tested this on two stock Galaxy Nexus phones and the light works on neither.  The screen IS off when I run the tests and all other apps on the phones trigger the lights without issue.

Answer (score 9):

If you use setDefaults(DEFAULT_LIGHTS) or setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL), it will ignore FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS and any calls to setLights(). I found that on my phone, the defaults would not light up anything. So do not use DEFAULT_ALL or DEFAULT_LIGHTS, and play with the RGB color if necessary... although 0xff00ff00 should work in pretty much all cases.

Comment: No lights with this: .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
         .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)

Comment: What kind of phone? Rooted? Custom ROM?

Comment: Galaxy Nexus stock and I have also tried with an HTC Evo Android 2.3 phone.  I have reworked the post to show this upated information.

Answer (score 7):

The LED works when the device is turned off (not powered off :P). To test write a simple app to create notification with delay and during the delay turn off the phone and wait to see the LED blink.

Answer (score 7):

Came across this today..if its still useful...
Only certain notifications with a priority - HIGH,MAX will be able to cause the LED to glow,
while those with lower priority LOW,MIN should not.
Adding this should make the LED glow...

builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)

Comment: Also DEFAULT priority causes the LED to glow.

Answer (score 6):

4 the lazy people:

```
private void testNotification() {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setOngoing(true);
    builder.setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to turn on the screen lights when a notification is received, I'd suggest using `PowerManager` and `WakeLock`. Following is the code to turn on the screen using mentioned classes:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                 | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                                 | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

NOTE: Don't forget to release the wakeLock using `wakeLock.release();`, otherwise the screen will remain turned on.

P.S. User can also turn the screen off using lock button. I have done same in my app. I am not using `wakeLock.release();` and leave it to the user to turn off the screen.

Comment: Since API 19, this is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

I have tried my code below, and it works fine for me. My mobile is Nexus 6P:

```
mBuilder.setContentTitle("APP_NAME")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtxt, UUID.randomUUID().hashCode(), new Intent(mCtxt, ReceivePushActivity.class), Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL))
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                //.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setVibrate(new long[] {0, 1000, 200,1000 })
                .setLights(Color.MAGENTA, 500, 500)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notify_logo);

        Notification ntf = mBuilder.build();
//        ntf.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
//        ntf.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
//        ntf.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyId, ntf);
```

Just remove all 'DEFAULT_ALL' settings.

Answer (score 1):

I also fought with this for ages! Leds worked nicely in Samsung devices but on others, no luck at all. I finally found a solution though; setup listeners to screen on and off events:

```
registerReceiver(this.screenOnListener, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"));
registerReceiver(this.screenOffListener, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"));
```

Then add set and cancel of the notification on those listeners:

```
public class ScreenOffListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public ScreenOffListener() {}

    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
    {
        Notification notif = new Notification();
        notif.ledARGB = "0xFFFF0000"; // Red
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notif.ledOnMS = 200; 
        notif.ledOffMS = 200; 
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
    }
}

public class ScreenOnListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public ScreenOnListener() {}

    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
    {
        NotificationTest.nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

Works for me now. For some strange reason the notification needs to be set at this time or the led doesn't work. Everything else in the notification works when set at anytime...

Note: the color and on/off times do not really work for at least for blinking leds. They are defined by HW and LPG (Led Pattern Generator) so that they work also in deep sleep when CPU is more or less off and so the patterns and colors supported depend on the HW you have. Most systems have only one blinking pattern and the colors might be reduced to full on full off R, G and B (and combinations). For fully lit leds all colors seem to be available.

Answer (score 0):

```
.SetLights (Color.Red.ToAndroid (), 300, 300)
```

Comment: it's actually 'setLights', and there's no 'Color.Red.ToAndroid()'.

Answer (score 0):

Add default Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS.

Example:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(baseCtx)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setDefaults(
                      Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                    | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
                    | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
            )
            .build();
```